# Stop RStudio always opening source viewer when in debug mode when evaluating R code

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio

I often code functions in the following way  by creating a basic function, entering debug mode, and then writing the function in debugmode. E.g.,

```
myfun <- function(x) print(x)
debugonce(myfun)
myfun("test")
```

The benefits of this is that I can get real time feedback on whether my code is working with the arguments passed to it.

However RStudio appears to have recently changed it's behaviour to make this more difficult. I recently upgraded to 2021.09.0 Build 351.

Previously, it would open the Source Editor when you call this command.
[image: rstudio debug viewer]

But if you closed this screen, you could return to your code, edit the code, evaluate code, and so on without the viewer re-appering.
However, now it seems to reappear every time you evaluate your code.
For instance, if I close the viewer, go back to my main script, and evaluate `x`, the Viewer opens back up.
This is super annoying for someone used to editing and evaluating code while in debugmode using the source script file.

Is there any way of entirely disabling the Source Editor view in Rstudio? Or alternatively, is there a way of being able to edit and evaluate code without the Source Editor constantly re-appearing in Rstudio (like how it used to work)?

My current fix is to downgrade to [Version 1.3.1093](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/older-versions/), where you could edit and evaluate code without the Viewer constantly re-appearing. But it would be a shame to miss out on future upgrades.

Comment: This is probably a better question for https://community.rstudio.com/ or https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues

Comment: @MrFlick Fair point. I've posted https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/9943 I'm not sure whether it makes sense to keep both questions open or not. If this question is open, I will share any insights from the github post here.

Comment: Not sure if you checked the existing issues first, but this looks like it may be related to: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/9918

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was principally a bug that has now been fixed.
At time of posting, downloading a daily build fixes the issue, but eventually this fix will be incorporated into beta and standard builds.
https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/9943